# Multiple Topics Versus SingleTopic in Google PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

While designing an event delivery system with 10 different event types,I see two options to model topics on Google PubSub. Either each of the event type can be queued in a different topic or all the 10 events can be queued in the same topic. Each of the events will have different subscribers and it's possible to queue the events in the same topic but filter messages on the subscriber side. I am looking for a very high throughput with minimal latency, should I go for a single topic or multiple topics?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Pub/Sub with different message types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842401/google-cloud-pub-sub-with-different-message-types)

Comment: Take a look at subscription filters: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering. Don't filter manually at the subscriber.

Answer (score 2):

Filtering on the subscriber side isn't a good idea: you will use more resource (and cost more money) and you will inject latency (if the message is received by the wrong subscriber, it is rejected,...)

So, there is 2 solutions:

- Create as many topics as you have type of event. But it's at the publisher to perform the filter and to publish in the correct topic. In addition, if you have new event types, you need to create a new topic and condition to deliver in it. Not ideal
- Create only one topic and to filter at the subscriptions level (not the subscribers level as proposed in your question). For this, you need to add the event type as PubSub message attribute and then  you can create [the subscriptions that you want on the correct attribute filtering rule](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering). The publishers don't know how the message are consumed and in case of new event type, simply create a new subscription with the correct filter.

Comment: Filtering on the subscription seems to be the correct solution, but the filter syntax is verbose and filters are limited to 256 bytes, so what is the solution when you have more than a few event types to filter on?

Comment: I never reached the 256 bytes limit of the filter feature. It's a filter on an attribute and most of the time it's a short filter. I haven't solution for that. Maybe open a feature request, or to reduce the size of your attribute values, maybe prefix them to have smaller filters.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Here's an example taken from an existing system, currently using RabbitMQ as the message bus. I've abbreviated identifiers more than I'd like (and swapped in dummy names), and it still doesn't come close to the limit, nor provide any headroom for future growth.
`(attributes.src="src1" AND (attributes.evt="eventType1" OR attributes.evt="eventType2" OR attributes.evt="eventType3")) OR (attributes.src="src2" AND attributes.evt="eventType2" OR attributes.evt="eventType4" OR attributes.evt="eventType5" OR attributes.evt="eventType6"))`

Comment: The alternative, as I see it, is that the publishers will need to know who/what will be consuming their messages and then publish to the correct (or even multiple) topics.

Comment: Is it a pull or a push subscription?

Comment: We are using pull via the .NET client library.
`<PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1" Version="2.7.*" />`

Comment: Looks like we'll try adding a new message attribute dedicated to routing via the filter. This requires the publisher to know about the subscriber(s), which is not ideal, but it seems like the least bad solution at the moment.